# Assertion fails for the number of points, on OpenCV's solvePNP

Tags: c++, opencv

Consider the following code:

```
  std::vector<cv::Point2f> vecUV = Vec2DFromFile(argv[2]);
  std::vector<cv::Point3f> vecXYZ = Vec3DFromFile(argv[3]);

  cv::Mat matCalib(3, 3, CV_64F);
  cv::setIdentity(matCalib);

  cv::Mat matRot(3, 1, CV_64F);
  cv::Mat matTrans(3, 1, CV_64F);

  cv::Mat matDistortion = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 1, CV_64F);

  cv::solvePnP(vecUV, vecXYZ, matCalib, matDistortion, matRot, matTrans);
```

Where vecUV and vecXYZ are both size 4. This fails with:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, 5), ipoints.checkVector(2, 6))) in solvePnP, file /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.4.1-r5/work/opencv-3.4.1/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp, line 65
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(3.4.1) /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.4.1-r5/work/opencv-3.4.1/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp:65: error: (-215) ( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, 5), ipoints.checkVector(2, 6)) in function solvePnP
```

I don't understand why the assertion fails given that I have 4 points for each vector. I tried stepping into it with gdb, to no avail:

```
...
(gdb) s
cv::_InputArray::init (this=0x7fffffffe350, _flags=-2130509811, _obj=0x7fffffffe2f0)
    at /usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:67
67      { flags = _flags; obj = (void*)_obj; }
(gdb) s
cv::_InputArray::_InputArray<cv::Point_<float> > (this=0x7fffffffe350, 
    vec=std::vector of length 4, capacity 4 = {...}) at /usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:85
85      { init(FIXED_TYPE + STD_VECTOR + traits::Type<_Tp>::value + ACCESS_READ, &vec); }
(gdb) s
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, 5), ipoints.checkVector(2, 6))) in solvePnP, file /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.4.1-r5/work/opencv-3.4.1/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp, line 65
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
0x00007ffff6e7334f in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
   from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/libstdc++.so.6
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815605/opencv-assertion-failed-with-solvepnp),m [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808702/opencvsolvepnp-assertion-failed) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815605/opencv-assertion-failed-with-solvepnp), but it does not seem to be the same case - there, a wrong parameter type was to blame.

[.zip with minimum reproducible example](http://marius2.mooo.com/files/ex.zip) - pass the input files as second and third parameters, first parameter is reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/). Since you are using `3.4.1` version, the documentation for `solvePnP` is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d).

It is `objectPoints` first then `imagePoints`.